# System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][SQL Server]Query timeout expired

Tags: c#, sql-server

SQL Server version: MSSQL 2012 64-bit
MS OS version: Windows Server 2012 Standard R2 64-bit 
IIS version: 8.5
Database Recovery Mode: Full

The architecture described below:

Client ---------> Server (IIS)  ------------> MSSQL DB
           https                            ODBC

1) Our application (written in c#) running at Server  uses ODBC driver( ODBC interface) to access the MS SQL Database.
2) Our application receives hundreds of request (string of length between 240 byte to 420 byte) from client in any given seconds. 
3) Each of this request is processed concurrently. Upon receiving this message:
     3.1 Begin Transaction
     3.2 Updates a table[XXXXXX] 
     3.3 Perform Select query on table[YYYYYYYY] to check if the message received exist in table[YYYYYYYY] or not. 
     3.4 Perform Insert/Update on table[YYYYYYYY] based of the Select query. 
     3.5 Commit Transaction
  *** The issue happens at item 3.4 after sometime and throws exception (stated below) and Rollback Transaction is performed:
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][SQL Server]Query timeout expired
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

What could cause the exception to occur? Is there any setting need to be set?

Link below is the sql script used to create the database.

Thank You.

Regards,
Kishen Sivalingam

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qF0QFfoVxd0d841mCp5YBEiG7d9uPIEDpEdgs8xAuoI/edit?usp=sharing